# Switch don't detect all posibles cases are covered

Tags: swift

There is a compile error with code similar to the following example:

```
func test(first: Bool, second: Bool) -> Bool {
    switch (first, second) {
    case (true, true):
        return true
    case (true, false):
        return false
    case (false, _):
        return false
    }
}
```

Error: Switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause

However all possible cases are covered. Does anyone know a solution without adding a **unnecessary** default case?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it will tell you to add a `default` clause anyway... If you edit this `switch` block in the future at least you will still have the default case.

Comment: Yes, but makes no sense, it should work

Comment: You may file a [bug report](https://bugreporter.apple.com) if you wish. But you can always add a `default:break` (or `default:return false`), to quiet the compiler, so there's no actual problem here. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Yes, but you are forced to write code that never will be reached. In this case  I would need also return a boolean, in this case it's easy but not always

Comment: So write the code and file the bug report. Don't complain to me about it. :) You're not actually having a programming problem; you're just whining. You _know_ what to do. And no one here can tell you anything that will make you happier.

Comment: Thanks, I will file a bug report. And sorry, I did not want to complain to you, just asking

Comment: It's covered in case (false, _):
        return false

Comment: @juancazalla the funny thing is that if you reorder the cases so that your last "case (false, _):" would be the first, compiler starts to be happy.

Comment: So it is definitely a bug, thanks for the appreciation @invisible_hand

Comment: @matt Finally some people have told me things that made me happy ;).

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

Making the code in this order will satisfy the compiler.

```
func test(first: Bool, second: Bool) -> String {
switch (first, second) {
case (true, true):
    return "True,  true"
case (false, _):
    return "false, _"
case (true, false):
    return "true, false"
}
```

Comment: `_` is the *wildcard pattern* in Swift. `case (false, _)` covers both `case (false, true)` and `case (false, false)`.

Comment: If you have two Boolean variables and more than four possible cases, you know you have a problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem is only when the last case is case (false, _). It seems a bug in the compiler or lint. Thanks!

I do not understand why people value negative, it seems that they have not understood the problem

Answer (score -6):

```
default:
    print("This is the default case")
}
```

Yo must include it into your switch statement

> Every switch statement must be exhaustive. That is, every possible value of the type being considered must be matched by one of the switch cases. If it’s not appropriate to provide a case for every possible value, you can define a default case to cover any values that are not addressed explicitly. This default case is indicated by the default keyword, **and must always appear last**.
>
> Switch Statements Must Be Exhaustive
>
> In Swift, every possible value of the control expression’s type must
> match the value of at least one pattern of a case. When this simply
> isn’t feasible (for instance, when the control expression’s type is
> Int), you can include a default case to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP's code isn't exhaustive.

Comment: @AnthonyRoani although you are correct about "switch statements must be exhaustive", the OP code is really exhaustive without default keyword. Look at last comments under original question as a reference.